# How to make .exe file

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a Windows application in VB.Net (.net framework 3.5 | Visual Stuido 2010). I dont know how to make .exe file of that app.

please help me.. I am a professional PHP web developer and new to .net Windows Programming

Comment: There is already an exe in your /bin/debug folder for your project.  Every time you compile and run a new exe is created.

Comment: Right, but make sure you switch to "Release" mode and look in `bin/Release` for the executable when you want to, you know, release/distribute the app.

Comment: Thank you guys.. But in .net 4.0 i found make .exe under file , and here not available.. where as they both are same IDE VS 2010. is there any option like that?

Comment: That option does not exist in Visual Studio. It never did, no matter which version of the .NET Framework you're targeting. Perhaps you're talking about an old version of Visual Basic from pre-1998? Yes, that had a "Make EXE" command under the File menu. It also had a completely different build model, nothing to do with the current versions of VB. Time to get a book on .NET Windows Programming.

Answer (score 4):

Once you've written the code for your application you can use the build solution or build project buttons as shown here.

Afterward use the [project directory]\bin\release or [project directory]\bin\debug folders to find the resulting exe as @Cory Gray mentioned in the comments.

[image: Build Application]